# Disable double tap in UITextView

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I want disable double tap  in UITextView. I already disabled long press with:

```
- (void)addGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        gestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    }
    [super addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    return;
}
```

I have tryed to do the same with UITapGestureRecognizer, but it's forbids single tap too.

```
- (void)addGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        gestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    }
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        gestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    }
    [super addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    return;
}
```

What can I do to disable only double tap?

I know about numberOfTapsRequired method, but dont know how exactly apply it in my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of disabling your tap gesture recognizer, I suggest you to try this

```
if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
    [(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
}
```

In this way you should have the single tap enabled and the double tap disabled.

Comment: I have tryed. Got "Property 'numberOfTapsRequired' not found on object of type 'UIGestureRecognizer *'.

Comment: Ok, that's because the downcast to `UITapGestureRecognizer` (`UITapGestureRecognizer` subclass) was missing...I edited my answer, now it works

Answer (score 0):

The default value of numberOfTapsRequired is 1, set it to 2.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I know it. And if I will do it, the result will be the same (will be blocked all taps). I need something like: "if (doubleTap) >>> gestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;"

Comment: Did you dry creating a gestureRecognizer for two taps, with an action which just does nothing?

Comment: Yes, that's didn't worked. But I dont sure, that did it right.